# Is it possible for sharepoint to automatically populate a folder with a specific file when a new folder is created?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an excel file that I would like to be in each folder that a user creates in a certain directory in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Use Document Sets instead of folders. (A Document Set is implemented as a special kind of folder.) You can preload folders and files in the Document Set. Your user just adds a new Document Set (a content type), instead of a Folder.

Document Sets are not fully supported in the Modern UI yet.

There's a series of steps to set up document sets.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-3DBCD93E-0BED-46B7-B1BA-B31DE2BCD234

Answer (score 0):

You can also use code to programmatically add an item to the folder after create a folder.

You would use the Add() method of the Items collection which creates and returns a new SPListItem. Then, you would initalise the new item with some values.

More information check the similar [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c146322a-da85-44de-be4d-193ffaa71eec/how-do-i-automatically-add-subfolders-when-i-create-a-folder-in-a-list-or-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy).